# Select the first date in an outcome analysis

Tags: r, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

Having the following dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(PatientID = c("1000285","1000317", "1000399","10006485","10995700317" ), MI = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","FALSE" ), dateMI = c(NA, NA, "2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", NA),A = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE" ), dateA = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2019-02-14"),  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to create a column named `"outcome"`. And this will be defined by this:

```
df$outcome = ifelse(df$MI| df$A == 'TRUE', 'TRUE' , 'FALSE')
```

Now, the question is that I need to create a column named `"date of the outcome"` and I want to fill this column with the following condition:

If `df$outcome==TRUE` I want the column `df$date_of_outcome` to be filled with whichever date happens first from `df$dateMI` or `df$dateA`, otherwise, fill it with NAs.  So I would end up with a dataset like this:

```
 test <- data.frame(PatientID = c("1000285","1000317", "1000399","10006485","10995700317" ), MI = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","FALSE" ), dateMI = c(NA, NA, "2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", NA),A = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE" ), dateA = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2019-02-14"), outcome= c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE" ), date_of_outcome = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", "2019-02-14"),  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Could anyone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your data has dates and logical values stored as string. We can change them to it's respective types.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('date'), as.Date), 
         across(c(MI, A), as.logical)) -> test
```

Then use `pmin` to get minimum of `dateMI` and `dateA`.

```
test %>%
  mutate(outcome = MI | A, 
         date_of_outcome = pmin(dateMI, dateA, na.rm = TRUE))

#    PatientID    MI     dateMI     A      dateA outcome date_of_outcome
#1     1000285 FALSE       <NA> FALSE       <NA>   FALSE            <NA>
#2     1000317 FALSE       <NA> FALSE       <NA>   FALSE            <NA>
#3     1000399  TRUE 2008-10-26  TRUE 2008-10-26    TRUE      2008-10-26
#4    10006485  TRUE 2008-10-26  TRUE 2010-11-06    TRUE      2008-10-26
#5 10995700317 FALSE       <NA>  TRUE 2019-02-14    TRUE      2019-02-14
```

Answer (score 2):

Her is what you need:

```
test <- data.frame(PatientID = c("1000285","1000317", "1000399","10006485","10995700317" ), MI = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","FALSE" ), dateMI = c(NA, NA, "2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", NA),A = c("FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE" ), dateA = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2019-02-14"),  stringsAsFactors = F)

test$outcome = ifelse(test$MI == 'TRUE' | test$A == 'TRUE', 'TRUE' , 'FALSE')

test$`date of the outcome` = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  test$`date of the outcome`[i] = ifelse(test$outcome[i]=='TRUE', as.character(min(as.Date(test$dateMI[i]), as.Date(test$dateA[i]))), NA)
}
```